# Stack head and tail updating to same value but only calling update on head- C programming

Tags: c, pointers, memory, stack

I am writing a program to add two strings of integers and push them onto a stack to add them.

For some reason when I call the push method it is only pushing the very last digit of the number onto the stack.

```c
#define list_data(l) ((l)->data)

typedef struct ListElmt_{ 
    void *data; //void pointer data because we cant point it to whatever
                //kind of datatype that we want
    struct ListElmt_ *next; //next pointer which points to next element

}ListElmt;

/*
 * Singly-linked list
 */
typedef struct List_{
    int size; //number of elements that we want in the list

    int (*match)(const void *key1, const void *key2);
    void(*destroy)(void *data); //destroy is a pointer to a function that 
                                //takes a void pointer and returns void

    ListElmt *head;
    ListElmt *tail;

}List;

/*
 Public interface

 */

void list_init(List *list, void (*destroy)(void *data));
//a constructor for the list

int list_ins_next(List *list, ListElmt *element, const void *data);
//takes a list parameter, the pointer to element and a constant void parameter
//if return type is 0 then it is success

int list_rem_next(List *list, ListElmt *element, void **data);
//pointer to list, second parameter is the pointer to the next element
//third parameter is a pointer to a pointer allows caller to have a pointer to the pointer for the data that got removed


#define list_size(list)((list)->size)
//creates a function to access the size of the list

#define list_head(list)((list)->head)
//creates a function to access the head pointer of the list

#define list_tail(list)((list)->tail)
//creates a function to access the tail pointer

#define list_is_head(list, element)((element)==(list)->head ? 1 :0)
//returns true or false if the element is the head of the list

#define list_is_tail(element)((element)->next == NULL ? 1:0)
//returns true or false if the element is tail of the list if nextpointer is Null

#define list_is_data(element)((element)->data)
//takes an element pointer and gets the data in the element

#define list_next(element)((element)->next)
//takes an element and gets the next element
```

List Init Function:

```
    number->size = 0; //initializes size and a destroy function
    number->destroy = destroy;
    number->head = NULL;//initializes head and tail pointer
    number->tail = NULL;

}

typedef List Stack;

#define stack_init list_init

#define stack_destroy list_destroy

int stack_push(Stack *stack, const void *data);

int stack_pop(Stack *stack, void **data);

#define stack_peek(stack)((stack)->head==NULL ? NULL: (stack)->head->data)

#define stack_size list_size
```

Insert Function for the stack:

```
    ListElmt *new_element;
    //allocate storage for the element;
    if(((new_element) = (ListElmt *)malloc(sizeof(ListElmt))) == NULL){
        return -1;
    }

        //insert the element into the list
    new_element->data = (void *)data;
    if(element == NULL){
        /*Handle insertion at the head of the list*/
        if(list_size(stack)==0){
            printf("The list size is 0: \n");//if list is empty then new head is also tail
            stack->tail = new_element; //sets tail as new element
            printf("The tail is this jeint: %d\n",*(int *)stack->tail->data);
            new_element ->next = stack->head;//new element's next pointer is old head
            stack ->head = new_element;
            printf("This is the head of the stack: %d\n",*(int *)list_head(stack)->data);
            printf("This is the tail of the stack: %d\n",*(int *)list_tail(stack)->data);
        }else{
            new_element ->next = stack->head;//new element's next pointer is old head
            stack ->head = new_element;
            printf("This is the head of the stack: %d\n",*(int *)list_head(stack)->data);
            printf("This is the tail of the stack: %d\n",*(int *)list_tail(stack)->data);
        }


        //lists head points to new element
        //lists head and tail are the same, head has a next poitner to null

    }else{
        printf("We made it to the else: ");
        if (element->next == NULL){
            stack->tail = new_element;

        }
        new_element->next = element->next;
        element->next = new_element;

    }

    stack ->size++;
    return 0;

}
```

List remove function:

```
int list_rem_next(Stack *stack, ListElmt *element, void **data){

    ListElmt *old_element;

    if(stack_size(stack)==0){
        return -1; //checks if the size if 0 because you can't remove anything
    }
    /*remove the element from the list*/
    if(element == NULL){
        //handle removal from the head of list
        *data = stack->head->data;
        old_element = stack->head;
        stack->head = stack->head->next;

        if(stack_size(stack)==1){
            stack->tail = NULL;
        }
    }else{
     //handle removal from somewhere other than the head
        if(element ->next == NULL){
            return -1;

        }
        *data = element->next->data;
        old_element = element ->next;
        element->next = element ->next->next;
        if(element->next == NULL){
            stack->tail = element;
        }

    }
    //Free the storage allocated by the abstract data type
    free(old_element);

    //Adjust the size of the list to account for the removed element
    stack->size --;
    return 0;
}
```

Push method

```
int stack_push(Stack *stack, const void *data){
    return list_ins_next(stack, NULL, data);
}
```

Pop function

```
int stack_pop(Stack *stack, void **data){
    return list_rem_next(stack,NULL,data);
}
```

Function to get size of string:

```
int getsize(char *s){
    char *t;
    int size=0;
    for(t=s;*t !='\0';t++){
        size++;
    }
    return size;

}
```

Function to add the numbers:

```
void addLargeNumbers(char *number1, char *number2){  
    Stack num1;
    Stack num2;
    Stack answer;

    stack_init(&num1,free);
    stack_init(&num2,free);
    stack_init(&answer,free);

    int length1 = getsize(number1);
    int length2 = getsize(number2);

    for(int i=0;i<length1;i++){

        int chartonum = number1[i]-'0';
        int *test1 = &chartonum;
        printf("This is chartonum: %d\n",chartonum);
        printf("This is test1: %d\n",*test1);
        stack_push(&num1,test1);
        printf("Just pushed: %d\n",*test1);

    }

    for(int j=0;j<length2;j++){
        printf("We are about to push %c in the second stack \n",number2[j]);
        int chartonum2 = number2[j]-'0';
        int *test2 = &chartonum2;
        stack_push(&num2,test2);

    }



    int* checking;
    stack_pop(&num1,&checking);
    printf("This is the number we just popped: %d\n",*checking);


    printf("This is the size of stack1 %d\n",num1.size);
    printf("This is the size of stack2 %d\n",num2.size);

    int carry;

    while(num1.size >0 && num2.size >0){
        int *result1, *result2;
        stack_pop(&num1, (void **) &result1);
        stack_pop(&num2, (void **) &result2);

        printf("This is the number we just popped from stack1: %d \n",*result1);
        printf("This is the number we just popped:%d \n",*result2);

        printf("result1: %d\n",*result1);
        printf("result2: %d\n", *result2);
        int sum = *result1 + *result2 + carry;
        printf("sum:%d\n",sum);
        int leastSigDig = sum % 10;

        printf("lsd: %d\n", leastSigDig);

        /* Push the least significant digit of the sum */
        stack_push(&answer, &leastSigDig);

        /* Carry the most significant digit to the next cycle */
        carry = (sum > 9) ? sum / 10 : 0;
        printf("carry: %d\n", carry);
    }

//    printf("Result: %d\n", *(int *)answer.head->data);

    printf("Stack size check: %d\n", answer.size);


    while(answer.size)
    {
        char* elem;
        stack_pop(&answer, (void**) &elem);
        printf("%s", elem);
    }
    /* Probably better to return the answer rather than print... */
}
```

Main:

```
int main() {
    addLargeNumbers("153","329");



    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

This is the output

```
This is chartonum: 1
This is test1: 1
The list size is 0: 
The tail is this jeint: 1
This is the head of the stack: 1
This is the tail of the stack: 1
Just pushed: 1
This is chartonum: 5
This is test1: 5
This is the head of the stack: 5
This is the tail of the stack: 5
Just pushed: 5
This is chartonum: 3
This is test1: 3
This is the head of the stack: 3
This is the tail of the stack: 3
Just pushed: 3
We are about to push 3 in the second stack 
The list size is 0: 
The tail is this jeint: 3
This is the head of the stack: 3
This is the tail of the stack: 3
We are about to push 2 in the second stack 
This is the head of the stack: 2
This is the tail of the stack: 2
We are about to push 9 in the second stack 
This is the head of the stack: 9
This is the tail of the stack: 9
This is the number we just popped: 3
This is the size of stack1 2
This is the size of stack2 3
This is the number we just popped from stack1: 3 
This is the number we just popped:9 
result1: 3
result2: 9
sum:12
lsd: 2
The list size is 0: 
The tail is this jeint: 2
This is the head of the stack: 2
This is the tail of the stack: 2
carry: 1
This is the number we just popped from stack1: 3 
This is the number we just popped:9 
result1: 3
result2: 9
sum:13
lsd: 3
This is the head of the stack: 3
This is the tail of the stack: 3
carry: 1
Stack size check: 2
```

Comment: can you show the structure definition of the list?

Comment: updated it :):)

Comment: Referring to this line (and the comment right after it): `int *test1 = &chartonum;`  This is only chartonum for the infintesimal amount of time before it goes out of scope and wanders off into undefined behavior territory.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is a list of strings, you need to have a separate memory for the string per node.

You are using `new_element->data = (void *)data;` This tells me that you are just copying the pointers. You need to allocate new memory for each string in the insert function by using `malloc` or `strdup`

Comment: The memory is allocated in the if statement right before that line

Comment: The memory for the element is allocated, but the `data` is also a pointer. This also needs to have memory allocated. You really do not need to use such a complicated structure for your stack, since you are storing characters anyway, But, if you insist on using this, you need to allocate memory for `data` and `free` at the end of the program